# Failed dependency while installing Iron browser (a Chromium web browser clone)

Tags: linux, google-chrome, browser, centos

Installation failed while trying to install Iron browser.

```
[root@localhost softwares]# rpm -ivh iron64.rpm 
error: Failed dependencies:
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.15)(64bit) is needed by iron64-29.0.1600-2.x86_64
    libudev.so.1()(64bit) is needed by iron64-29.0.1600-2.x86_64
    libudev.so.1(LIBUDEV_183)(64bit) is needed by iron64-29.0.1600-2.x86_64
```

When tried to install it using Yum it failed also.

[Here is the link to the Iron browser website](http://www.srware.net/en/software_srware_iron.php). I am using CentOS 6.4. Google Chrome is already installed.

Comment: WE NEED MORE INFORMATION!

Comment: What have you tied installing with yum?

Comment: FYI Iron is not a Chrome clone. Both Chrome and Iron are forks of Chromium.

Answer (score 0):

Libudev is not available in centos by default. Try with some other repo, like epel.

Libc is provided by glibc. Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17778107/rpm-install-in-centos6-does-not-recognize-dynamic-library-libc-so-6) if it does not get recognized